# Apache Ignite as transparent cache for Postgresql tables

Tags: java, postgresql, caching, ignite

Is it possible to use Apache Ignite as transparent cache for several tables in PostgreSQL RDBMS and to query that cache using Ignite SQL?

For example like this:

Application (via SQL) ---> Apache Ignite (if data is not loaded) ---> Postgresql

I'm new to Ignite and cannot figure out how to do that or is it even possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignite's SQL works over in-memory data only so you need to load data into caches beforehand. In other words, read-through doesn't work for SQL queries.
Starting with version 2.1 Ignite provides its custom [persistent store](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store) that allows running SQL queries against the data both in memory and on disk.

Answer (score 4):

It will work, if you preload data to cache before querying.

You can do it by configuring a CacheStore and calling IgniteCache#loadCache(). Here is documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/3rd-party-store#cachestore

Another option is to enable [readThrough](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/3rd-party-store#section-read-through-and-write-through) parameter and use cache API. Unfortunately, this option has no effect on Ignite SQL and works for cache API only.